# How to create Draw Interactive rectangle with eyeShot

Tags: cad, eyeshot

I am trying to write an autocad-like software with the eyeshot library, but I have difficulty performing the rectangle drawing function, can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What Eyeshot build are you using?
Maybe this article can be helpful:
https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217842948-AutoCAD-like-selection-style-v7-

Comment: @ilCosmico I think he meant drawing interactively like he would click somewhere and it set the rectangle first corner and on the mouse over he probably wants an overlay rectangle showing until he click the second opposite corner.